# "Unsupported modules detected" when adding kotlin multiplatform support to library

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an android library what I am trying to turn into a kotlin multiplatform library. When I use the kotlin multiplatform plugin in android studio to create a new KMM module and try to compile I get an error saying

```
Unsupported modules detected: Compilation is not supported for
following modules: 
.sharedmodule.androidAndroidTestRelease, 
.sharedmodule.commonMain, 
.sharedmodule.commonTest, 
.sharedmodule.iosArm64Main, 
.sharedmodule.iosArm64Test, 
.sharedmodule.iosMain,  
.sharedmodule.iosTest, 
.sharedmodule.iosX64Main,  
.sharedmodule.iosX64Test.  
Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.
```

so basically all the stuff that got added to create the KMM module

this is the gradle file that gt created via the plugin

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
}
kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "sharedmodule"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting{
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.4.1"))
                implementation(kotlin("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:1.4.1"))
                implementation(kotlin("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:1.4.1"))
                implementation(kotlin("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.4.0"))
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting{
            dependencies{
//                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:1.3.8")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }

    packagingOptions{
        excludes.add("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}
val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework =
        kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix the errors?

Comment: How are you trying to compile?